# How to use condition inside the return inside map

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching the data from map. I am getting an error while checking the the status. How can I use condition inside return?

```js
{item.status}===0&& 
<button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"onClick={() =>Switch(item.status,item.id)}>
<div className="handle"></div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is React you need to wrap your JSX elements around a single root element for it to be able to render it. So your code would need to change to (if i understood correctly)

```
if (item.status === 0) {
    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary btn-toggle"  data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"onClick={() =>Switch(item.status,item.id)}>
            <div className="handle"></div></button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the rest of your code please so we can better help you out?

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your code try this:-

```
{!item.status && (
   <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"onClick={() => Switch(item.status,item.id)}>
     <div className="handle"></div>
   </button>
)}
```